# Is there some sort of accessible "Session ID" that both the Client and Server know of within a WCF Service call?

Tags: wcf, session

Looking for this session identifier for logging purposes...

Comment: Have you tried [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally WCF services should be stateless.  The default is for them to be stateless without a session id that would tie the server to the client.  Unless you have a really good reason (outweighing the performance hits) to maintain state, I'd keep them stateless and sessionless.

That said, you can have per-session WCF services which will allow you to do what you're asking.

This article ([link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFInstance.aspx)) goes into some detail on instance management with WCF.

For in-depth discussion, take a look at Chapter 4 in Juval Lowy's Programming WCF Services ([link](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494/)) which is all about state management in WCF services.